# Auto linebreak not working for Linux

Tags: css, linux, wordpress, line-breaks

I currently work on a website (using WordPress) and want text to use linebreaks where needed (ergo, when a long word could be splitted in order to make the line's word spacing look adequate).

In my theme options CSS I defined the following:

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
}
```

This works fine with Mac and Firefox when using Windows, but my Linux Firefox does not work accordingly.

Did I miss any Linux-specific declaration? How would I achieve automatic word-breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the lang-attribute?

```
<article lang="en">
```

If your lang-attribute is set, there needs to be a appropriate hyphenation dictionary implemented in your browser.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens):

> On HTML, the language is determined by the lang attribute: browsers will hyphenate only if this attribute is present and if an appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available.

In Firefox this has been implemented end of January (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253317) maybe it hasn't hit the Linux Version yet...

Comment: I already defined the lang attribute, so unfortunately that did not do the trick.